# Men get Alhour Alein, what do women get?

Tags: jannah, houri, men-women

We all know that when Muslims who die while believing in Islam and go to heaven will be rewarded many things from Allah, one of these things is exclusively for men which is [(Alhour Alein)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houri) or the "Fair women":

> كَذَلِكَ وَزَوَّجْنَاهُم بِحُورٍ عِين
>
> Thus. And We will marry them to fair women with large, [beautiful] eyes.
>
> [Quran 44:54]

Allah is Fair, but all rewards are for both men and women except for this, which appears to be exclusively for Muslim men.  Presumably, Muslim women would receive their own equivalent reward; is there any indication in the Qur'an or the Sunnah of what this reward would be?

**UPDATE:**

Some said that in Arabic when directing words to both men and women then the Male form of the words is used. That is 100% correct. But when using the feminine form then it is for sure describing Females and not Males.

Allah used Feminine form when talking about AL-hour in Quran:

> (كَأَنَّهُنَّ بَيْضٌ مَّكْنُونٌ) [Alsaffat: 49]
>
> (إِنَّا أَنشَأْنَاهُنَّ إِنشَاء* فَجَعَلْنَاهُنَّ أَبْكَارًا* عُرُبًا أَتْرَابًا) [Alwaqi'ah: 35-37]
>
> (فِيهِنَّ قَاصِرَاتُ الطَّرْفِ لَمْ يَطْمِثْهُنَّ إِنسٌ قَبْلَهُمْ وَلَا جَانٌّ* فَبِأَيِّ آلَاء رَبِّكُمَا تُكَذِّبَانِ* كَأَنَّهُنَّ الْيَاقُوتُ وَالْمَرْجَانُ) [Alrahman: 56-58]
>
> (فِيهِنَّ خَيْرَاتٌ حِسَانٌ* فَبِأَيِّ آلَاء رَبِّكُـمَا تُكَذِّبَانِ* حُورٌ مَّقْصُورَاتٌ فِي الْخِيَامِ* فَبِأَيِّ آلَاء رَبِّكُـمَا تُكَذِّبَانِ* لَمْ يَطْمِثْهُنَّ إِنسٌ قَبْلَهُمْ وَلَا جَانٌّ) [Alrahman: 70-74]

All the above Ayas (verses) are about Alhour Alein and in all of them Allah used the Feminine form in Arabic to describe them which only means one thing, Alhour Alein are Females.

*P.S. I cannot translate the above Ayas accurately to English because there is not feminine form of grammar in English.*

Comment: As a matter of fact the wikipedia article (which you linked) discusses this VERY topic in depth and dismantles the idea that it is only women.  -1 for not doing research.  A large number of sources are given in the article which are from both, Qur'an and Hadith (no credibility issues with this article at least).

Comment: Wikipedia is not a trusted source when it comes to Islamic Fatwas. I could not find a reliable source about this issue that's why I asked here perhaps someone can give me an answer with proper proof.

Comment: That is not the case.  Translations are provided and comments from the translator are added in.  Just because the word is feminine does not mean that its meaning is feminine.  For example Samaa' (sky) is feminine, but the sky has no gender. Also notice that Samaa' does not end in the Taa' Marbuta which is commonly associated with feminine case.  Lastly there are Masculine words which have endings generally associated with feminine gender ( the names osama and hamza are easy ones that come to mind).

Comment: No, sorry but you do now know the basics of arabic. For example `كَأَنَّهُنَّ بَيْضٌ مَّكْنُونٌ` Allah used كــأنهــن which is EXPLICITLY for women, If god wants it to be for all then Allah would have used كأنـــهم. Please remember it is a whole Aya (sentence) not a single word!!!

Comment: Let's stop this and Please read "Tafseer Ibn Katheer" or any other Tafseer of your choice and you will see that I am correct.

Comment: **Alhour Alien"" .... why alien

Answer (score 4):

Alhour Alein are not only female. There are also male Alhour Alein.

There are different verses about Alhour Alein. Some talk about female Huri but some without any gender.

In Arabic when there are group mix of men and women the male pronoun is used for them.

So if Quran says Huri is for them it not mean only for men. It means for them (both men and women)

Also some verses say: for them [who arein paradise] is whatever they wish. So a woman simply can wish a male Huri!

In fact it should be asked what is your proof Huri is only female. This is only a misunderstanding in mind people and has no basis. Even if there are descriptions about female Huri this not mean no male Huri exist.

Comment: In Arabic when we use the feminine then it is female, Allah used the feminine form when describing Alhour. so they are Females.

Comment: Ahmadi, They are only Female. Read my question after the update.

Comment: @HaLaBi if you read my answer caefully I said some verses talk about female huri as you showed some OK. but still some verse talk about Huri without any gender. like 44:54 saying we give them (a group of women and men) Huri (without any gender). so this verse means there are male huri also. and as I said Quran says what they wish. a woman wish a male Huri. can not wish? if can not wish so Quran is lying. also I say from some Hadith from Ahl Bayt. not from myself.

Comment: Prof that hoor is only female not male. [source](http://foodiefahoodie.blogspot.com/2011/11/hoor-their-correct-gender.html)

Answer (score 0):

<s>OK, I will get DVs for this answer too, but I feel like have to say these...</s>

The terms in Quran, `Rical (Man)` and `Nisa (Woman)` are not the genders we humans and other creatures actually have in this planet.

When Allah says "male", he implies both men and women in our understanding. When he says "female", he means a different kind of categorization.

Quran is a `muteshabih (symbolic)` book. You mustn't take its expressions and way of speeches directly. They are not directly corresponding to the same meanings in our world.

I don't want to say anything more, because my knowledge is still incomplete about this subject. I'm still doing research on it. And be sure that you can't find a better answer then this over the internet.

---

So;

`بِحُورٍ عِين` means "hooris with eyes". `Eye` has a very special usage in several ayats. Like `قُرَّتُ عَيْنٍ` in 28:9. `Eye` is a special organ profusely used with both itself and its feature "to see" in both Quran and in knowledge of old ummats (the mythology).

So, the those `hooris` are probably for both women and men, and don't carry a characteristic gender in our metrics; but does in another metric.

Comment: I disagree, the translation is wrong. Please read Sahih International/Tafseer Ibn Katheer or ask any Native Arab.

Comment: Also, there are hadiths that explicitly say that they are women.

Comment: "حور مقصورات في الخيام" [Quran, Alrhman:72] Gos used the feminine way in this Aya (مقصورات) which can not be used to describe men. So for sure (Alhour) are females.

Comment: Of course they are women. I didn't say they were male. But in a different metric.

Comment: May Allah Complete you your understanding about the matter.! But, I see it is not good to answer such an important question with *incomplete* *(in your language)* knowledge

Comment: if the things you say are true then one can also argue that in Quran the word male means female and the word female means male.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of women is modesty,
and the lack of women to men is not as a lack of men to women - as is well known-

> وعن أسامة بن زيد رضي الله عنهما عن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال‏:‏ ‏"‏
>   ما تركت بعدي فتنة هي أضر على الرجال من النساء‏"‏ ‏(‏‏(‏متفق
>   عليه‏)‏‏)‏‏.‏
>
> Usamah bin Zaid (May Allah be pleased with them) reported: The Prophet
>   (PBUH) said, "I am not leaving behind me a more harmful trial for men
>   than women".
>
> [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

So Allah doesn't Motivates women to the Paradise in thing women ashamed of it.