# What women will get after death?

Tags: women, jannah

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Men get Alhour Alein, what do women get?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1107/men-get-alhour-alein-what-do-women-get)

I am concerned about the part after people go to heaven.

Men will get to marry beautiful virgin women called "hoor" or "hur"

> “They will recline (with ease) on thrones arranged in ranks. And We shall **marry them to Huris (fair females**) with wide lovely eyes.”  (52:17-20)
>
> Wearing [garments of] fine silk and brocade, facing each other.
>   Thus. And We will **marry them to fair women with large, [beautiful] eyes**. [44:53-54] (Sahih International)

Also it is mentioned they will have a great figure.

> Indeed, for the righteous is attainment
>   Gardens and grapevines
>   And full-breasted [companions] of equal age [78:31-33] (Sahih International)

But there is nothing said about women. What happens to them?
Also does it matter whether she died being married (once, twice or more), widowed or single?

Comment: @Ershad that question has no good answer

Comment: It IS a dupe. Having no good answer doesn't mean you can ask the question again :o)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there is great deal of material on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houri). You should've sifted through the references and verified them yourself and arrived at a better question .

Secondly, hoor are promised both for virtuous men and virtuous women.

I  don't quite remember the reference, but I seem to recall a verse which loose is translated as those who are virtuous will meet your virtuous spouse in Heaven, and those who are virtuous and do not have a virtuous spouse, will be granted one. I don't remember the reference, and hopefully someone can point it out and I will improve the answer.

Having said that, and assuming that the above verse does not exist for the sake of argument, there is another aspect to this question. Why does the gender matter?

In Quran, there are only references to Hur, and there is no description. The descriptions which allude to female form are in hadith. Is it not beyond the possibility that the hadiths in question were asked by male audiences and hence the answer was adapted to relate to them. Imagine, if asked by men what Hoor look like the and the description was that of a man.

Perhaps, if it had been asked by a group of females, the answer would've been different.

Having said that, I think it does not matter what the hoor are. From Allah, who has given us so much, made the sun and the moon and other stars, the heaven and the earth and everything in between, for us to doubt or debate whether the hoor's we get are male or female is unfathomable.

It is pretty clear that all pious men AND women will get stream of honey and milk and hoor's (and other rewards), so can we leave it at that. This is an area which is only in Allah's knowledge and it serves us no purpose in this world. When this knowledge would be required, we would see the hur's in person and know what they are, hence the question would become moot.

> “They will recline (with ease) on thrones arranged in ranks. And We shall marry them to Huris (fair females) with wide lovely eyes.” (52:17-20)

Huris translation to fair females is a mistake. Hurs have no gender and their exact form is only known to Allah.

> Wearing [garments of] fine silk and brocade, facing each other.
> Thus. And We will marry them to fair women with large, [beautiful] eyes. [44:53-54] (Sahih International)

Ask yourself if Allah can create heaven and earth and everything in between, and not have a companion for mominaat (female Muslims). To me it just sounds incredulous.

Additionally, Dr Zakir Naik has an explanation on youtube.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q7f9LTqNpGc