# my question is that men will get reward in paradise in form of hoor , will women be given any reward?

Tags: women, jannah, akhirah

In the Quran, it is mentioned that men will be given hoor in paradise if they have done good deeds.

but it is not mentioned that if women have done good deeds than what will she get in the world hereafter?

Comment: I think this already been answered, there are many questions about hoor here.  https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1107/men-get-alhour-alein-what-do-women-get/1112#1112